# An apache injection attack?

Tags: apache, server-side-scripting

I encountered a novel (to me anyway) form of injection attack in one of my
logs

```
login as <!--#exec cmd="ls .."-->
```

Which looks like someone it trying to trigger sever side includes on
an apache server, if the input text was echoed into an error message.

Can apache even be configured to process SSI on it's output stream?
Or is there some more subtle vulnerability it's trying to exploit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SSI_Injection_%28OWASP-DV-009%29) shows how to do black box probing to test for SSI Injection exploits using text very similar to what you describe.

An exploit would certainly be possible in the case that the text is written to a file and subsequently served by the webserver that supports SSI (whether or not that site otherwise uses SSI at all).  I am not aware of a way that Apache can process SSI in the output stream.